# Positioning inside of div with flexible left element height

Tags: css, html

I have a div with a fixed width = 950px;

inside of it i have 2 divs - one has float left ,second - float right.

left - is a text div , right - picture with text to the left of it, height of picture is fixed. How do i to make if a text after picture grows in width, left div(with text) squishes in width and grows in height.

thank you

Comment: no idea what you're talking about. post your html & css or set up a http://jsfiddle.net please.

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: My mind was blown in this one.

Comment: Is this what you try to do? http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/CtTN7/

Comment: Or is it more like this? http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/CtTN7/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CtTN7/3/
  problems was - when i make smth bigger then word Bacon, to squish left thing
i guess i did it,lol, thx Mathias.
gonna try it on real page , and if it not work for some reason i will ask you again,ok?

Comment: @AlexanderCapone Make sure you ask a proper question where you include any relevant code that you have.

Comment: @Mathias, make an answer, going to give you +1
you pushed me to right direction thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderCapone I added an answer but even if I pushed you in the right direction I am not sure what you want your end result to be. If you can please show how you would like it to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `float: right` on the image and place it inside the text `<div>`. Like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/CtTN7)**

Or you can use something new and experimental like `display: flexbox` if this: **[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/CtTN7/2/)** is the result you want.

Comment: that flex shiat is crazy nice :D too bad this can (should) only be used in future :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Style="width:auto"
```

for both divs.

Comment: try with both Height:auto and width:auto.

Comment: Try to rephrase your queries a little better. Couldn't understand much of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it into a table with % value of width set in left and right position.